# Efficient resampling with Python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I want to resample a sequence as follows:

```
fastadict = {"seq1" : "ATGCAGTCACGT", "seq2" : "ATGTGTGTACG"}
```

I wrote the following function:

```
import sys
import random

def resampling_f(fastadict, seq, num):
    fastadict[seq] = fastadict[seq].replace("N","").replace("n","")
    l = []
    new_seq = ''.join([random.choice(fastadict[seq]) for i in range(num)]) 
    l.append(new_seq)
    return l

# Run function for 20 replicates:
for i in range(20):
    print resampling_f(fastadict, "seq1", 10)
```

This works fine for a small sequence as in the example. In my work, I need to sample about 1 million letters (base of DNA, ACTG) for 10000 times. This function is too slow for this purpose. Is there a faster way of obtaining sampling with replacement with python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `numpy.random` module which provides vectorized sampling together with view casting:

```
>>> n, k = 20, 10
>>> 
>>> np.random.choice((*fastadict['seq1'],), replace=True, size=(n * k,)).view(f'U{k}')
array(['GCAGAATGCT', 'GGAGGTGCAT', 'CACCATCATT', 'CGTGGTGTAC',
       'AGAATATCGG', 'GATTTTGGCC', 'GAACATAAGC', 'CGGGCCAAGC',
       'GTTGGTGTTT', 'GACCAATAAC', 'ACCCGTAGCC', 'GAATTCCCGG',
       'AACAGGTCAC', 'AGACAAGCAC', 'CACACTTGCC', 'CGTTTGTAAT',
       'CTAGCCCTCG', 'CTCGACATAT', 'GATGATTAGA', 'TCTATCCTCA'],
      dtype='<U10')
```

Python 2 version:

```
>>> np.random.choice(tuple(fastadict['seq1']), replace=True, size=(n * k,)).view('S{k}'.format(k=k))
```

Speed:

```
>>> from time import perf_counter
>>> n, k = 100, 1000000
>>> t0 = perf_counter(); x = np.random.choice((*fastadict['seq1'],), replace=True, size=(n * k,)).view(f'U{k}');t1 = perf_counter()
>>> t1-t0
1.29188625497045
```

Comment: What is 'S{k}'?

Comment: Depending on the value of `k` this will be formatted into for example `S10` which is interpreted here as a numpy dtype. 'S' stands for string, 10 is the maximum length. Note that this applies for Python2. In 3 you would use 'U' for unicode.

Answer (score 1):

I compared your version using `random.choice` with another version using `random.uniform`. The latter is faster. The later resamples by generating random numbers based on the length of the string, and puts it as the index of the string.

Here are the two functions to compare : your `resampling_f` and `resample_new`.

---

```
import random
import time

fastadict = {"seq1" : "ATGCAGTCACGT", "seq2" : "ATGTGTGTACG"};

def resampling_f(fastadict, seq, num): 
    fastadict[seq] = fastadict[seq].replace("N","").replace("n","") 
    l = [] 
    new_seq = ''.join([random.choice(fastadict[seq]) for i in range(num)]) 
    l.append(new_seq) 
    return l

def resample_new(data, num):
    new= ''.join([data[int(random.uniform(0,num))] for i in range(num)]);
    return new
```

Rather than `fastadict[seq].replace....` inside the loop, do it outside the loop so that it is done only once.

---

Here is the code to compare them :

```
start_1=time.time();    
# Run function for 20000 replicates: 
for i in range(20000): 
    print(resampling_f(fastadict, "seq1", 10))
total_1=time.time()-start_1;


start_2=time.time();  
data = fastadict["seq1"].replace("N","").replace("n","");
# Run function for 20000 replicates: 
for i in range(20000): 
    print(resample_new(data, 10))
total_2=time.time()-start_2;

print("First one: "+str(total_1));
print("Second one: "+str(total_2));
```

---

I got the `total_1` is `3.6` secs, and `total_2` is `2.966` secs.

If 200,000 resamples, i got the 1st one `37` secs, and 2nd one is `28` secs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason it's slow is that every time you call random_choice, it's ranging over the whole series. You could instead range over the series once, count how many times each item appears, and then sample from that distribution, e.g. using [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html).